# Vue-Router not rerouting in Single Page Application (Vue/Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to get `vue-router` to work in a `Vue.js/Laravel` project. I have the following simple pages:

**home page:**

[image]

**about page** (scrolled down in single page):

[image]

Made from these files:

**welcome.blade.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=WeakMap"></script>
  <title>title</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
  <div id="app">
    <app></app>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

**app.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <home></home>
      <about></about>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import About from "./about"
import Home from "./home";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    About,
    Home,
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

**home.vue:**

```
<template>
  <section class="home" style="background-color: yellow; height: 100vh">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "home"
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

**about.vue:**

```
<template>
  <section class="about" style="background-color: green; height: 100vh">
    <h2>About Page</h2>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "about"
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

**web.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});
```

**app.js:**

```
require('./bootstrap')

import Vue from "vue"
import App from "../vue/app"
import router from "./router";

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: { App },
    router
})
```

**router.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import Home from "../vue/home";
import About from "../vue/about";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        { path: "/", component: Home},
        { path: "/about", component: About}
    ]
});
```

Now, if I add   `<router-view></router-view>` to `app.vue` like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <home></home>
      <about></about>
    </main>
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

The site doesn't load at all and the browser console shows no errors:

[image]

Path `localhost:3000/about` shows an `404 Error`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to define base in router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Then in app:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
   <nav>
     <router-link
      to="/"
      tag="a"
      >Home</router-link>
     <router-link
      to="/about"
      tag="a"
      >About</router-link>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but the outcome doesn't change. The browser window stays empty.

Comment: Hey mate, sorry :(  maybe you have repo of your project so i can clone it to try to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you need a catch-all route that redirects all routes to your Vue project:

Create a new controller called something like `VueController`, then direct all your routes in Laravel to it:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'VueController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Then in your `VueController` return your `welcome` blade:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class VueController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```